# Git "unable to determine absolute path of git directory"

Tags: git, windows-7

I'm a git newbie and am having problems trying to get the latest version of a remote project:

```
S:\dev\prj\myprj [master]> git pull
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 266: cd: .git: No such file or directory
Unable to determine absolute path of git directory
```

It was working fine until today and strangely I don't think I've changed anything since it last worked fine.

This is on Windows 7.  My project is on an encrypted drive (S:) and git is on C:

```
S:\dev\prj\myprj [master]> git --exec-path    
C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_656cc1ef6d04f06ddf8b2f5bedbac921caed3b62/libexec/git-core
```

Manually doing a cd to the exec directory above works fine (even though there are mixed slash types).

Any ideas how to even start working out what has gone wrong?

Comment: Install msysgit and try from it's shell if you haven't tried that yet.

Comment: ok, it looks like there's some confusion going on here.  I had two git GUI's installed and the powershell was getting confused between the two.  I uninstalled both and then reinstalled one of them and it seems to work now.

Comment: Running Windows Server 2012 R2 on XenServer?

[You may need to remove or update your guest tools][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21550808/939250

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found the solution/workaround!  Hurrah!

I was (and still am) using GitHub for Windows, and occasionally it asks me to go to Windows Powershell to fix the repository because sometimes it can't do it automatically, and occasionally it would fail with the above error message.

The reason it was failing for me was not just that my project was on an encrypted drive but, more importantly, that sometimes I would start GitHub for Windows before mounting the encrypted drive (which I manually mount).  Even if I then close GitHub for Windows, then mount the encrypted drive, and then relaunch GitHub for Windows it would still come back with the above error, so perhaps not everything GitHubby is being shut down when I close GitHub for Windows.

The workaround for me is to:

1. Reboot
2. Mount Drive containing project
3. Launch GitHub for Windows

...in that order.

Comment: in my case I just had to reboot PC

Comment: yep, same here. Reboot fixed the problem.

Answer (score 36):

Killing the **ssh-agent.exe** process works for me.
Note: It is called **sh.exe** in newer versions of SourceTree (thanks @cowlinator)

Comment: This worked for me too by entering the following into PowerShell: `Stop-Process -processname ssh-agent*` followed by `git pull`

Comment: Matt's restart option would work, however this is the easiest. Cheers!

Comment: Seemed to be called 'sh.exe' in newer versions of SourceTree.

Comment: Way better than the chosen solution. Thanks!
Note: it also works for Git Extensions.

Answer (score 5):

You're most likely using PowerShell and a mapped network drive. PowerShell "helpfully" undoes the mapping, so the directory passed to Git is a UNC path which Git doesn't understand.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I am indeed using Powershell. However I've been gitting from powershell for months with no problems, and today `git push` still works - it's only `git pull` that's broken. Wtf?

Comment: An easy hack workaround is to just type 'cmd' in PowerShell, do the 'git pull', then type 'exit' to go back to PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SourceTree on Windows, try Tools- > Options -> Git -> Use system Git