# git shell on Windows reports "sh.exe has stopped working (APPCRASH)"

Tags: git, msysgit, xen, windows-server-2012-r2

I have tried both the Git shell installed by [GitHub](http://windows.github.com/) and that provided by [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) on my Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual machine on XenServer 6.20

With each, git command line calls fail with the message

```
sh.exe has stopped working (APPCRASH)
```

This is a recent problem.  Can anyone advise me of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be caused by the XenServer 6.20 Guest tools I installed after first installing git.

There is an update for Windows Server 2012 R2.  Alternatively, you can uninstall the guest tools, which is what I did.

FYI, I also posed this solution at [jira.atlassian.com](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1215)

Comment: FYI: it may be an issue with XenServer itself that becomes more apparent when guest tools are installed, because these tools speed up the O/S.

Answer (score 1):

This error went away after building GIT for Windows from Sources (version 3.2)

The instaler on the official page is too old.

See this post for detailed instructions on how to build from sources:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/build-git-windows-sources

And this other post on how to workaround the issue:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/git-shell-windows-reports-shexe-has-stopped-working-appcrash