# git error for Windows 10: "Unable to determine absolute path of git directory"

Tags: git, windows-10, git-submodules

I am starting to get the following error from git after I switch to Winodows 10 recently.

```
git submodule -q update --init --recursive: Unable to determine absolute path of git directory
```

Does anyone know what this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539076/git-unable-to-determine-absolute-path-of-git-directory

Comment: @AbdullahWasi I tried the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539076/git-unable-to-determine-absolute-path-of-git-directory, it does not work. I could not find ssh-agent.exe or sh.exe, and I do not have a mounted drive.