# Cant use git in windows (Such file no such file or directory)

Tags: windows, git, github

im trying to use git on windows but when i want to initialize a local git repository i get "Such file no such file or directory". But this only happens on certain directories if i try to use it from downloads for example I can use it, I cant clone repositories as well.

```
$ git init
C:/Users/casas/Desktop/.git: No such file or directory
```

I don´t know whats happening can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't try and create a Git repository in Desktop: this is not a good place to store sources for a project.

Second, check if you are [using powershell and a mount drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11539109/6309).
Or check if you are [using SourceTree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21375551/6309).

Try instead to use a regular CMD, and `git init myrepo`: that will create a myrepo folder (with a `.git` in it)

Make sure to use the [latest Git for Windows 2.21](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).